# How to draw signature on canvas in Metro using C# and XAML

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I am looking to allow my user to draw their signature in a canvas within a Windows 8.1 Metro application. I dont want to use pointer events, I want user to swipe his finger on surface screen to do signature.

Does anyone know of any examples using C# and XAML?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Canvas>   
<Rectangle Width="80"       
       Height="80"
              Fill="Red" 
             Canvas.Left="80" 
             Canvas.Top="80" />
</Canvas>
```

Refer link:

http://georgiakeays.me/Csharp/137159983163349.html

Comment: Its using pointer events. These events are not raised when user swipes his finger on surface screen to do signature. These events are raised when we try to draw using mouse.

Comment: Pointer events do get raised for touch input just as well as they do for mouse or pen input.

Comment: You might get into a problem though if your `Canvas` is inside of a `ScrollViewer` since that can intercept touch input events for panning.